# I want to create 10 levels with one button but this code shows only level 1?

Tags: adafruit, sketch, hardware, variables, led-strip

```cpp
#include <Adafruit_NeoPixel.h>
const int PIN = 4;
const int NUMPIXELS = 10;
const int BUTTONPIN = 6;
int buttonState = 0;
int PINState = 0;
int level = 1;
int dt = 100;
Adafruit_NeoPixel pixels(NUMPIXELS, PIN, NEO_GRB + NEO_KHZ800);

void setup() {
  pixels.begin();
  pinMode(BUTTONPIN, INPUT);
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop(void) {
Serial.println(buttonState);
  buttonState = digitalRead(BUTTONPIN);
  if (digitalRead(BUTTONPIN) == HIGH) {
    if (buttonState == 0) {
      buttonState = 1;
    } else {
      buttonState = 0;
    }
  }

  if (buttonState == 1) {
    opdracht(level);
  }
  else {
    if (level >= 10) {
      level++;
    } else {
      level = 1;
    }
    pixels.clear();
  }
}

//level 1
//void opdracht1() {
//  pixels.setPixelColor(0, pixels.Color(150, 0, 0));
//  pixels.setPixelColor(5, pixels.Color(0, 0, 150));
//  pixels.show();
//}

void opdracht(int x) {
  if (x == 1) { //level 1
    pixels.setPixelColor(0, pixels.Color(150, 0, 0));
    pixels.setPixelColor(5, pixels.Color(0, 0, 150));
    pixels.show();
  }

  if (x == 2) { //level 2
pixels.setPixelColor(8, pixels.Color(150, 0, 0));
pixels.setPixelColor(6, pixels.Color(150, 0, 0));
pixels.setPixelColor(1, pixels.Color(0, 0, 150));
pixels.show();
  }
```

Comment: I think `if (level >= 10) {` should be `if (level < 10) {`?

Comment: Your button reading code doesn't work. It only registers a button press if the button is pressed, when the code is exactly between the two digitalRead lines. Which is very unlikely. Try adding a few more variables, instead of trying to use the `buttonState` for three different purposes. Hint: use `buttonState` for the current state of the button; use something like `oldButtonState` for the state of the button in the last loop; and use something like `buttonPressed` to indicate when the button is first pressed down (which you then use to increment the `level`)

Comment: thank you! I will try to use the oldButtonState and buttonPressed.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to ask a question. So I will assume the intended question is
“Why does this code always show level 1?” and I will try to answer that.

The variable `level` is defined here:

```cpp
int level = 1;
```

Its initial value is 1. Then it is updated here:

```cpp
if (level >= 10) {
  level++;
} else {
  level = 1;
}
```

The first time this section of code runs, `level` has its initial value,
namely 1. The condition in the `if` evaluates to false, then the
statement

```cpp
level = 1;
```

is executed, which assigns the value 1 to `level` (which has no effect,
as that was already its value anyway).

The next time that section of code runs, `level` has still the vale 1,
and the effect is the same as the previous time.

Comment: oow i understand it thank you!! what do i have to change to change the value?

Comment: @louisemoons: Under what condition do you want `level` to be incremented? Can you complete the sentence “`level` should be incremented if ...”?

Comment: Another, stronger hint. Your current code says "if level is greater than or equal to 10, increment it." It starts at 1, and no other code changes it, so that if statement will never be true. Don't you want to increment it if it is less than 10?

Comment: @EdgarBonet level should be incremented if pressing buttonpin